# What is the best way to shutdown hard disk?

Tags: linux, unix

Right Now I'm using hdparm command in unix to shut down the hard disk but there are few issues with it.

1. when it wakes back up it consumes
   lots power. Is there any other way
   to do it?
2. Many times when I put my
   hard disk to sleep, I can see few
   bursts at the beginning and then
   after a while it goes to sleep. I
   think its because of the journaling
   system in ubuntu (which I use) Have
   anybody encountered that?
3. What would
   be the best linux/unix operating
   system (eg: ubuntu/centos/redhat) to
   work on extensive hard disk
   operations?

I would highly appreciate if you could share the problems you encountered while doing this operation.

Comment: /bin/sh|any other application: input/output error, if disk doesn't comes back at first request

Comment: You will probably get a better answer for this on superuser.com

Comment: 1. It *starts to consume*, or *it consumes more than usual* - but for few first seconds?

Comment: @mhambra: For the first few seconds its not stable i.e. it goes to sleep and wakes back up two or three times and then goes to sleep for a long time. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Is it USB drive? USB peripherals are usually draining lot of power even when in power saving mode.

3. If you run multi-core/multi-processor machine, you should exclude any 64-bit distro, due to default kernel scheduler getting hangy with exhaustive I/O rates. Read here: [AMD64 system slow/unresponsive during disk access (Part 2)](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-793263-start-0.html), or you can switch to a kernel version, that has better scheduler: [ubuntu forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1474904.html)